# How do I overcome the issue of a TextView not fitting on the screen and also pushing other content off the screen?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, android-xml

I am trying to build a simple form and I want to add a note/header/title at the top displaying a message. I have tried to do it but the text has gone off the screen and the stuff below it has been pushed off as well. How do I counter this?

Here is my `layout.xml` and here it is on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/fNBfQiz8

```
<TableLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:shrinkColumns="1"
   android:stretchColumns="1" >

   <TableRow
       android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
       android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
       android:layout_width="match_parent" >
        <TextView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:text="You can only add a spot based on your current location" />

    </TableRow>

   <TableRow
       android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
       android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >
        <TextView android:text="Name:" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/name" />
    </TableRow>

   <TableRow
       android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
       android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >
        <TextView android:text="Address:" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/addr" />
    </TableRow>

   <TableRow
       android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
       android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >
        <TextView android:text="Type:" />
        <Spinner
           android:id="@+id/spinnerType"
           style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:entries="@array/types_array"
           android:prompt="@string/types_prompt" />
    </TableRow>

   <TableRow
       android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
       android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >
        <TextView android:text="Terrain:" />
        <Spinner
           android:id="@+id/spinnerTerrain"
           style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:entries="@array/ratings_array"
           android:prompt="@string/ratings_prompt" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="Difficulty:" />
        <Spinner
           android:id="@+id/spinnerDifficulty"
           style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:entries="@array/ratings_array"
           android:prompt="@string/ratings_prompt" />
    </TableRow>

   <TableRow
       android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
       android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >
        <TextView android:text="Description:" />
        <EditText
           android:id="@+id/desc"
           android:gravity="top"
           android:inputType="textMultiLine"
           android:lines="2"
           android:maxLines="2"
           android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/save"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Save"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
       android:layout_marginTop="2sp" />
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: have you put both `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. A thought that may work...

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yeah I've put it in both the TextView and the encapsulating TableRow. It solves text off the screen problem but the other widgets are still gone.

Comment: That's good, maybe try adding those two lines to each of your `TextView`, `EditText`, `Spinner`, and `Button` tags. I don't think you need it in the `TableRow`, but not sure on that. I am still fairly new to Android, but I think that each visible component has to have those two attributes, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally understand what issue you're having without seeing a picture, but I took at a look at your pastebin.  As a general comment, the root view in a layout (the ScrollView, in your case) should probably have `match_parent` or `fill_parent` for both its width and height, else you may see some weird rendering where you see blank areas where no layout is covering the screen or get some odd scrolling behavior.

[Here is a good tutorial which does nifty things with the spacing of the columns in TableLayouts and may help you figure out why your views are getting cut off and otherwise not fitting into the proper space.](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/)  Take special note of which attributes he uses on his TableRows and their children in order to achieve the layout he wants.

As for your question of wanting to display some header information, I can think of two options.

1. If you want them to appear fixed to the top of the screen while the TableLayout scrolls, create a LinearLayout to act as the root view for your layout and set its orientation to vertical.  Add your header as the first child to this LinearLayout and your ScrollView as the second.
2. If you want the header information to scroll with the Table, keep the ScrollView as your root and create a LinearLayout (again with a vertical orientation) to be the only direct child of it. Add your header information as the first child of the LinearLayout and your TableLayout as the second.

Hope this helps.  If you posted a screenshot of what you're seeing now along with some type of mockup for the layout you're aiming for, it'll aid in isolating the issue you're having and help us in the community offer support.